# 3 phase motor, star wiring, neutral

Tags: motor, phase, neutral

Consider a normal 3 phase motor with star/delta, ***focusing on the star wiring here***... what would theoretically happen if I placed a neutral wire from the star connection contactor, to the electrical pannel neutral?
-would I get any amp load reading?
-would I get a higher amp load reading if the motor inner windings are imbalanced?
-would my neutral wire overheat and burn if it's too thin?
-what are the risks and benefits of doing this, I've seen post of someone claiming that this could help an imbalanced motor, with others stating that nobody does this and is not practical.

[image]

Comment: If the motor is built perfectly symmetric (both mechanic and electric) and the mechanical load torque is constant, there should be no current on the neutral wire. Of course the supply voltage should be symmetric too.

Comment: so by putting a multimeter at the star windings during star startup, you can check if the windings are faulty? besides the normal method of checking each phase load with an ampmeter